# Persist ui-grid's resizeColumns width settings in session storage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Just curious -- I have recently added the resizeColumns module onto the ui-grid in my web application.

All widths are being set to auto so that when a column is resized, the others automatically adjust their width accordingly and don't run off the screen or leave white space at the end of the grid.

Is it possible to persist the width setting of the columns in session or local storage so the user doesn't have to readjust the column width(s) every time they load the page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as you can access localStorage.

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("resizeColumnWidth")) {
  /* set the column width based on the value from local storage */
}

else {
    localStorage.setItem("resizeColumnWidth", resizeColumnWidth);
}
```

Comment: But how do I actually get the width value that the user set on the column? The column definition doesn't seem to have a width property.

Answer (score 0):

UI Grid has a `ui.grid.saveState` module that provides a couple of mechanisms for saving the state of the grid.

```
gridApi.colResizable.on.columnSizeChanged($scope, function () {
    const state = gridApi.saveState.save();
    // {"columns":[...],"scrollFocus":{},"selection":[],"grouping":{},"treeView":{}}

    gridApi.restore($scope, state);
});
```